# How to update drilldown data in highchart without redraw the chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, highcharts-ng, angular2-highcharts

I have implemented highchart - column chart with multiple level drilldown(3 levels). 3 levels of drilldown flow is working fine. Now the problem is when try to update the drilldown series, its always going to first level.

How to refresh the current level drilldown data without going to first level?

Comment: Hard to say when I can't see how you have implemented your chart. A potential solution could be to make a global state object that keeps track of where you are in the chart, i.e. how many levels of drilldown (and which). Then use that in `chart.events.redraw`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Series that are currently visible are available in `series` array of chart obejct. If you want to change them just call their `update` function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    chart.series[0].points[0].doDrilldown();
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {
    chart.series[0].update({
    color: '#bada55'
  });
}, 4000);
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1L4avxtw/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Comment: Update chart.series[0] data and trigger chart.redraw();. Now its working fine